# ionic framework error when run the command ionic capacitor build android

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using the ionic framework. I am trying to run the command `ionic capacitor run android`,

i got the error like the attachment.

Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: please anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: Did you run: ionic build then npx cap sync?

Comment: Thank you for your post. it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I just replace the `...\AppData\Roaming\npm` with my old data. Then it is working fine.